# Displaying Decimal places using printf method

Tags: java, format, printf

I am using the printf method to make a receipt-like console output.
it lists the items, their prices and the quantity, and then the total.

i currently have it all lined up the way i want to, although its not showing 2 decimal places. I need to show the full number, example : "$1.00", and it is currently showing "$1".

This is what i have

```
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-10s %-10s %-5s", "Item","Quantity","Price","Total\n");
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f %-10.2s %-5.2s %s", "Gum",gumQuantity,"$"+gumPrice,"$"+gumTotal,"\n");
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f %-10.2s %-5.2s %s", "Soda",sodaQuantity,"$"+sodaPrice,"$"+sodaTotal,"\n");
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f %-10.2s %-5.2s %s", "Chips",chipsQuantity,"$"+chipsPrice,"$"+chipsTotal,"\n");
    System.out.printf("%-52s %-5.2s %s", "Subtotal", "$"+subTotal,"\n");
    System.out.printf("%-52s %-5.2s %s", "Sales Tax", "$"+salesTax,"\n");
    System.out.printf("%-52s %-5.2s %s", "Total", "$"+totalFinal,"\n");
```

the output looks like this

```
    Item                           Quantity   Price      Total
    Gum                            10.00      $1         $1    
    Soda                           3.00       $1         $3    
    Chips                          20.00      $1         $2    
    Subtotal                                             $4    
    Sales Tax                                            $3    
    Total                                                $4
```

How can i get it to show the full values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that dollar sign in your first argument as currently you are trying to add decimal for `String` as `%-10.2s` instead of this you can try following way.If your price is `Integer/String` than you should convert it to `double` by `Double.valueOf(gumPrice)`

For example:

```
System.out.printf("$%-10.2f",12.7);//Pass double/float istead of String
                              ^
                              price
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the price and total as `String`, you may replace:

```
System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f %-10.2s %-5.2s %s", "Gum",gumQuantity,"$"+gumPrice,"$"+gumTotal,"\n");
```

with something like:

```
System.out.printf("%-30s %-10.2f $%-10.2f $%-5.2f %n", "Gum", gumQuantity, gumPrice, gumTotal);
```

**Note:**

1. `gumQuantity`, `gumPrice` and `gumTotal` should be of type `double` or `float`, otherwise you should cast them to the corresponding type and pass them to the `printf` method.
2. The dollar sign is now in the formatted string.